# What is the trick to identify which of these are true

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was hoping to not have to create a bunch of fictional sets so that I can solve this problem. Any trick or rules to this?

> The sets A and B are subsets of a universal set U. Which of the following relations is always true?
>
> (a) $A'∩ B' ⊂ (A ∩ B)'$
> (b) $B ∩ A ⊂ B$
> (c) $(A ∪ B) ⊂ A' ∩ B'$
> (d) $A ∪ B ⊂ A ∩ B$

Comment: Can you to explain your ideals about the problem? Thanks.

Comment: At least two of them are pretty transparent: you should be able to look at (b) and decide very quickly that it’s true, and at (d) and decide equally quickly that it’s not in general true and what kind of example will be needed to demonstrate this. That (c) is not generally true should also be pretty clear after a few minutes’ thought, and it would be hard *not* to find a counterexample. The only one that requires a bit more thought is (a), and a Venn diagram would quickly point you in the right direction.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Maybe it's just me, but isn't the phrasing of the question rather deceptive? That is, which of the following relations **is** instead of is/are...seems misleading to me.

Comment: @JBeckton Try [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/InteractiveVennDiagrams/) out for toying around with interactive Venn diagrams.

Comment: @crash: I don’t think that it’s intentionally deceptive: I expect that we’re seeing either sloppiness/carelessness or, just possibly, an idiolect a little different from ours. I’d probably have used *are* here, but in my idiolect it’s definitely ‘Which, if any, **is** always true’, irrespective of the number of true statements.

Comment: thanks! Used the Wolfram site before but did not see that tool yet.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Good point. I guess I was thrown off by the phrasing since, given my answer, I noticed that (a) is always true, but I essentially used a thought explicated in (d) [didn't notice (d) until just now, simply because I stopped after I saw (a) was always true]. Good ole language...that hideous/gorgeous beast.

Answer (score 1):

by [*De Morgan's laws*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): $A' ∩ B'=(A ∪ B)'$. I use this in (a) and (c)

(a) True: $A' ∩ B'=(A ∪ B)'⊂ (A ∩ B)'$. when a set decreases its complement increases.
(b) True: $x\in B ∩ A $ means $x$ is in both $A$ and $B$. so $x\in B$.
(c) always false:  $(A ∪ B) ⊂ A' ∩ B'\iff (A ∪ B) ⊂(A ∪ B)'$. a set is disjoint from its complement.
(d) this is not necessarily true; for example $A=\{1,2\} $ and $B=\{2,3\}$. (in fact this is true iff $A=B$)

Answer (score 0):

Draw the diagrams. And see which makes sense.

Comment: can you recommend an online Venn diagram tool?

Comment: https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/examples/venn_diagram_maker

Answer (score 0):

Use Venn diagram for d (counterexample).

Prove b by definition of subset relation (take an arbitrary element in the left set, show that it belongs to the right.

Use de Morgan law for a and c. Then use above mentioned method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply interested in quickly evaluating the truth or falsity of these sentences, rather than spelling out geometric or formal proofs, consider simply *translating the statements into English*. This can improve your intuition immensely.

- Statement (a) claims **neither A nor B** implies **not both A and B** (which is equivalent to **either not A or not B**).
- Statement (b) claims **both A and B** implies **B**.
- Statement (c) claims **either A or B** implies **neither A nor B**.
- Statement (d) claims **either A or B** implies **both A and B**.

These are informal translations, of course, and they can be made much more precise. For example, what statement (a) is really saying is that anything that is in neither A nor B is not in both A and B. Or, even more pedantically: the set of all things that are in neither A nor B is a subset of the set of all things that are not in both A and B.

Nevertheless, being able to translate fluently in this way is important.